# can't open new tab in react, adds localhost:3000 on link?

Tags: reactjs

i have used react router doms' Link:

```
<Link target="_blank" to={"www.mylink.com"} >mylink </Link>
```

but this would open new tab to http://localhost:3000/www.mylink.com 
also, using a href:

```
<a href={'www.mylink.com'} target="_blank" > mylink </a>
```

does the same. opens new tab to http://localhost:3000/www.mylink.com 
how do i open in new tab only the link?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

try this

```
<Link target="_blank" to={"//www.mylink.com"} >mylink </Link>
```

or this

```
<a href={'//www.mylink.com'} target="_blank" > mylink </a>
```

for more reference:
[Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls#answer-21828923)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier#Generic_syntax

Comment: This is brilliant. It helped me as well. Does anybody know, why is this the answer? I was trying to find in the docs but could not find it...

Comment: @lazar this is actually have a lot to do with how modern browsers works, not actually react problem. It is known that browsers would prepend the domain you are visiting to links that does not start with http:// or https:// or other protocols. This create problem when you have to specify explicitly http or https, thus modern browsers support the // to indicate that the browser does not need to prepend current domain

Comment: @am05mhz Thanks!

Comment: if your using variables  ```<Link href={`//${url_github}`}>link</Link>```

Comment: anyone please tell my why not do `<a href="www.mylink.com"  target="_blank"> mylink </a>` instead?

Comment: you can read the link attached in the answer, relative vs absolute url, start with `/` means url is directly after domain, `//` means its on another domain, without both is relative to current url path, next time please read thoroughly

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use Link but I had the same problem. Now I'm using this 
`onClick={() => { window.open('LINK','_blank')}}`

Answer (score 0):

When I used `Link` like

```
<Link to={`//${isHrefVlaue}`}></Link>
```

this was opening without localhost, but it was missing the colon in https and not working as expected.

But then it worked after I replaced `Link` with an anchor like

```
<a href={isHrefVlaue}></a>
```