# React app opens new tab with wrong url, https instead of https:

Tags: javascript, reactjs, url, react-router-dom, semantic-ui-react

I am using Link from `react-router-dom` package to make my `semantic-ui-react` `<Dropdown.Item>` component open in new tab some url. 
First my problem was that when I was clicking on this component, in new tab, url that I wanted to go to was appended to my localhost route, and I found the solution here on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47447458/5833816.
There it says that I should add // before my url, so not 'https://someurl.com' but '//https://someurl.com'

But applying this solution did not help entirely. Now in new tab url is not appended to already existing localhost url but instead of being opened with 'https://someurl.com' it opens 'http//someurl.com' - so, without :

Here is code:
Component:

```
<Dropdown.Item
    as={Link}
    to={url} // url was 'https://someurl.com', now is '//https://someurl.com'
    target={newTab ? '_blank' : ''} // newTab's value is true
    replace={newTab}
    className='contextDropdownItem'
    onClick={onClick}
    disabled={disabled}
  >
```

When I click on this dropdown menu item browser opens new tab, but url is http//someurl.com without :

Version of semantic-ui-react: 0.81.1,
react: 16.4.1,
react-router-dom: 4.3.1

Comment: I guess you should fill url as `url = "//someurl.com"` As well as change `to={url}` to `href={url}`

Comment: I did and nothing is changing. Still the same problem.

Comment: Might be related to the fact that `someurl.com` does not have https supports and redirects traffic to http.
```
$ curl -L https://someurl.com -I
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Location: http://someurl.com/?_xas=1fad09881044b512dd2cf83e7015c8e19e0bd774
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=0; includeSubDomains
Date: Mon, 24 Sep 2018 09:37:34 GMT
```

Comment: it does the same thing with http urls as well

Comment: hi, first, you already specify the protocol in your url, so no need to prepend `//`, its used to indicate absolute url or relative url, regardless of protocol. second, the linked question uses `<Link>` which translate to `<a>` that already have default onclick action, while you are using `<Dropdown.Item>`, i'm not a react expert, but i believe this component don't translate to `<a>`, and you have its onlick event manually binded to a function, check that function to see if you are redirecting the browser properly

Answer (score 0):

React-router doesn't support external links. Check out [React-Router External link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42914666/react-router-external-link) for a few ideas of how to get around this, but I tend to use standard `<a href='...'>`.